# Apify fingerpint spoofing

Tags: web-scraping, fingerprinting, audio-fingerprinting, apify

i have created an Actor on Apify cloud, and need to collect data from site which use anti-**scraping** protection.
Was found this article https://help.apify.com/en/articles/1961361-several-tips-how-to-bypass-website-anti-scraping-protections
But this not enough in my case.
I need to randomize font, canvas, webgl, audio context fingerprints.
Are there any way to do this with apify?

Comment: Apify has a rich toolset in this regard - you might want to also check this article:
https://help.apify.com/en/articles/3115265-using-stealth-mode-to-mask-headless-chrome
https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/stealth-options#__docusaurus In case it's still not enough, I recommend that you have a look here and request custom solution directly from Apify:
https://apify.com/marketplace

Comment: there are no problem to hide headless chrome.

Comment: There are problem to have different fingerprint for each actor run.
For example: i have the same canvas fingerprint over all task executions.
How i can to randomize it?